# How to get dbcontext access without an HTML page?

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I get access to the dbcontext without an HTML page?
I have a WebAPI project in which the classes from the HTML page can access the database, like this:

```
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
       private readonly Home5.Models.Home5Context _context;

       public CreateModel(Home5.Models.Home5Context context)
       {
           _context = context;
       }

       public IActionResult OnGet()
       {
           return Page();
       }
    }
```

But when I create classes of my own, I can't access the context, because I can't create an instance of the class without having the context to give it to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) shows the steps that are necessary to create a Web API that accesses a database using entity framework.

In order to use your `Home5Context`, the crucial steps are the following:

#### File startup.cs

[Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#register-the-database-context) the context with the dependency injection container. This is the component that creates the controller instances and provides them with an instance of your context, if configured correctly:

```
services.AddDbContext<Home5Context>(opt =>
           opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("Home5Database"));
```

Please note that there are several other options besides an InMemoryDatabase. The following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder?view=efcore-3.0#extension-methods) shows most of them.

#### Controller

Inject the context into the controller:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly Home5Context _context;

    public TodoItemsController(Home5Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // ...
```

After that, you can use the context and access the database in the controller.

---

Please see the sample or the [code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-web-api/samples/3.0/TodoApi). Maybe it helps to follow the sample in a new project and then change your current project.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i dont know how i can create an object of the MyController class or how i can use the methods in this class.